# Leading Zeros used in int

Tags: c, arrays, int, modulo, leading-zero

I am trying to complete a program but the leading zero gets removed when it is a read as an int. I need this leading zero in the event a user enters a zero at the start because I am using it to do math with later in the program and can't just add the leading zero in the printf.

```
printf("Enter the first 6 digits of the barcode: \n");
scanf("%i", &n1);
printf("Enter the first 6 digits of the barcode: \n");
scanf("%i", &n2);

//Splits number1 into individual digits
   count1 = 0;
   while (n1 != 0){
       array1[count1] = n1 % 10;
       n1 /= 10;
       count1++;
   }

   count2 = 0;
   while (n2 > 0){
       array2[count2] = n2 % 10;
       n2 /= 10;
           count2++;
//Steps 1-3
int sumo = array1[5]+array1[3]+array1[1]+array2[5]+array2[3]+array2[1]; //adds odd
int sume = array1[4]+array1[2]+array1[0]+array2[4]+array2[2]; //adds even without 12
int sumd = 3*sumo; //multiplies odds
int sum  = sume+sumd; //adds above and evens
int chec = sum%10;
int check = 10-chec;
```

Entire program can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/MitkmCXy)

Comment: So, scan using a string....

Comment: **You need to use `%d` to scan a decimal integer**, not **`%i`**. Especially when it has leading zeroes.

Comment: with `%i` sequences with leading zeroes are scanned as *octal* numbers, which means that 0149 will be scanned as **12**. not even 149. And definitely not with leading zeroes! Just unlearn the `%i`, it is always wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The leading zeroes are always going to be lost when you store the value as an Integer so you'll need to store the value as something else (probably a string)

Answer (score 0):

You should scan the input as a string instead of int. You can later change it to int (for calculating sum) using `atoi`.

Comment: `You can later change it to int  using atoi` Again you lost the leading zeros.

Comment: There is no direct way to add leading zeros to `int`, that's why there was a suggestion to use strings which will keep leading zeros intact. I suggested to use `atoi` for doing this kind of operation `array1[5]+array1[3]+array1[1]+array2[5]+array2[3]+array2[1];`

Comment: Why can't he directly add ASCII values representing the digits?

Comment: He can, but ultimately he needs the value as an `int`, right?

Comment: Based off what I have read I would need to use atoi and then convert it back to an int before doing the math for sum and such.

Answer (score 0):

> Leading Zeros used in int

First, improve code by:

1. Check the return value from `scanf()`.
2. Be sure to use `"%d"` instead of `"%i"` when leading zeros are possible with *decimal* input. With  `"%i"`, a leading 0 indicates *octal* input.  [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256203/leading-zeros-used-in-int/53256872#comment93398321_53256203).  This change alone with help OP.

   ```
   "%d" "012" --> 12 decimal
   "%d" "078" --> 78 decimal
   "%i" "012" --> 10 decimal
   "%i" "078" --> 7 decimal, with "8" left in stdin
   ```

Various approaches to find the leading `'0'` follow:

---

To count the number of characters entered, record the scan position before and after the `int` using `"%n"`. `"%n"` does not contribute to the return value of `scanf()`.

```
int n1;
int offset1, offset2; 
if (scanf(" %n%d%n", &offset1, &n1, &offset2) == 1) {
  int width = offset2 - offset1;
  printf("%0*d\n", width, n1);
}
```

This counts the *characters* and not just *digits* as `"+123"` has a width of 4.

---

A more robust approach would read input as a *string* and then process it.

```
// printf("Enter the first 6 digits of the barcode: \n");
char buf[6+1];
if (scanf(" %6[0-9]", buf) == 1) {
  int n1 = atoi(buf);
  int width = strlen(buf);
  printf("%0*d\n", width, n1);
}
```